# Get :first and :last with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pseudo-element

I had this problem:

> I was trying to do the Twitter Effect, so when you click on it, 
>   checks if it's either `:first` or `:last`, and if it isn't, create a
>   `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` just like in Twitter's Timeline. I
>   want to create this effect when clicking in any of "One phrase here".
>
> The main problem was that my jQuery code doesn't detect `:first` and
>   `:last`. I already tried also with `:first-child` and it did the same.

Using this HTML code:

```
<div class="phrases-container">
    <div class="phrases-title">Titulo</div>
    <div class="phrases-list">
        <div class="phrases-item zooming">First child</div>
        <div class="phrases-item zooming">One phrase</div>
        <div class="phrases-item zooming">One phrase</div>
        <div class="phrases-item zooming">Last child</div>
    </div>
    <div class="phrases-load-more">
        <a class="link loadMore">Get more phrases!</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using this jQuery code, I could fix it. Thanks for your help! (:

```
$(".zooming").live('click', function(){
    var $z = $('.zooming');
    index = $z.index(this);
    var bradiust = $(this).css("borderTopLeftRadius");
    if (bradiust == '0px') 
        var thand = "show";
    else 
        var thand = "hide";
    if (thand == "show"){
        if (index == 0 ){
            alert("This is the first");
        }else
        if (index == ($z.length-1)){
            alert("This is the last");
        }else{
            alert("This is just another");
        }
    }else{
        if (index == 0 ){
            alert("This is the first");
        }else
        if (index == ($z.length-1)){
            alert("This is the last");
        }else{
            alert("This is just another");

        }
    }

});
```

Comment: This question looks a lot like "write my code for me."  What have you tried? What isn't working?

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to do, and you also need to tell us what is going wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: I could not understand the problem, but just a tip about your code: do not use live(), it's really inefficient. Choose delegate() or on()/off() instead, if you have the latest jQuery.

Comment: @tvanfosson not at all, I created the function, just need to detect if it's `:first` and `:last`, if not, do that effect (Which I had written)

Comment: @Martin using `on()` makes my code die.

Comment: @Luis - all you are doing is alerting the choice (and badly since the scope of the variable will be just the if/else clause not the entire function). I don't see anything here that even remotely looks like you've tried adjusting the margins.

Comment: @tvanfosson i'm not asking for the `margin` or `border-radius` function, I have it already in my code. The `alert()` was to try if the `:last` or `:first` worked.

Comment: @Luis you're still using `var thand` wrong.  You need to declare it outside the scope of the if/else clauses then assign it.  `var thand; if (bradiust == '0px') thand = "show"; else thand = "hide";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what is wrong with `:first`, but how about this:

```
var $z = $('.zooming'),
    index = $z.index(this);

if (index == 0 || index == ($z.length-1)) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', '.zooming', function(){
    var L = $('.zooming').length-1;
    var I = $(this).index();
    if (I===0 || I==L) {
        return false;
    }else{
        var bradiust = $(this).css("borderTopLeftRadius");
        if (bradiust == '0px') {
            var thand = "show";
        }else{
            var thand = "hide";
        }
        alert(thand);
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't be fooled by the [:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) jquery selector:

> Description: Selects the first matched element.
>   The :first pseudo-class is equivalent to :eq(0)

You have to use the [:first-child](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) selector

Answer (score 0):

What about combining:

```
if ($(this).is(':first') || $(this).is(':last'))
```

But notice:
http://api.jquery.com/is/

> Starting with jQuery 1.7, selector strings with positional selectors
>   apply the selector against the document, and then determine whether
>   the first element of the current jQuery set matches any of the
>   resulting elements. So for the HTML shown above, an expression such as
>   $("li:first").is("li:last") returns false.